# Why QWERTY keyboard built this way?

Tags: keyboard, qwerty

I am curious about the qwerty keyboard,
why the buttons sorted in this specific way?
Does someone thought to change the layout in order to make pairs of letters to be more close in the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

In the days of the typewriters, some letters which are often used often jams when they are used frequently. To solve this problem, Christopher Latham Sholes attempted to solve this problem by placing them further away from each other. E. Remington eventually developed this into the QWERTY keyboard. When the computer was invented, most people are already used to the QWERTY keyboard and so it is continued to be used.